# Move Laravel 5 Eloquent models into its own directory

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

Laravel 5 has ORM models by default in app folder. I want to move these into app/models. When I do that then these classes are not found anymore.

How to make Laravel find the Eloquent ORM models from app/models?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just create a folder named `Models` and move your files into it. After that, change the namespace of the models from just `App` to `App\Models` (update the usages as well) and run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` was missing and now it works in combination with composer.json autoload. I did not want to start changing classes namespaces.

Comment: Don't forget to change the UserModel for Authentication if using it. See also here: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/11/changing-your-authentication-model

Answer (score 74):

## Solution for Laravel 5.6+

---

### 1. Move the files to the new directory

Say you want to move the models to `app/Models`

### 2. Change the namespace of the models

For each model change :

```
namespace App;
```

to

```
namespace App\Models;
```

### 3. Change the references in other files

Check these files and search especially `app\User`

- `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php`
- `config/auth.php`
- `config/services.php`
- `database/factories/ModelFactory.php`
- `database/factories/UserFactory.php`
- Your Controllers

And change `App/ModelExample` to `App/Models/ModelExample`

### 4. Autoload files

Run `composer dump-autoload`

### 5. Congratulations!

Comment: Just updated to 5.4 and was struggling a bit. Excellent instructions. Thanks.

Comment: @SaintPlay I tried above steps but it did not seem to work properly. Like few pages did work when I use models inside a controller. but some of the pages still throw `App\ModelName` Error. the model does not seem to reflect the change. I couple of times did dump-autoload and also did cache:clear, view:clear. How can I debug these issue?

Comment: @SaintPlay I get these when I do composer dump-autoload `Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Models\Company" was found in both "$baseDir . '/app/Models/Company.php" and "C:/Users/murli/laravel/Bookings/app/models/Company.php", the fi
rst will be used.
`

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia what version of laravel are you using?

Comment: @SaintPlay I am using Laravel 5.6, most recent one. I had to revert everything back to default. I failed to move all the model into models folder. I did php artisan confg:clear, cache:clear, view:clear

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia Seems like a case error. Make sure your folder and namespaces has the same case. By the way, I just updated the instructions to Laravel 5.6

Comment: You can also avoid having to change the namespaces and usages by just changing this in composer.json: `"psr-4": { "App\\": "app/" }` to this: `"psr-4": { "App\\": ["app/", "app/models/"] }`. This way, classes both in `/app` AND in `/app/models` will be in the `App` namespace (it's up to you to put models inside "models" and other stuff outside of it). I'm not sure it's something I'd recommend, as you can run into ambiguities and conflicts, but you should be fine as long as you don't have similar subpaths both in /app and in /app/models, and you don't actually use a "Models" namespace

Answer (score 16):

Add `"app/models"` to composer.json's classmap autoload section

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/models"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried it before and it did not work. Now it works thanks to lukasgeiter suggestion to use `composer dump-autoload` that made the classes to be found.

Comment: Thanks, this advice composer update is missing from other solutions I was reading, but it is the one that does the trick for me!

Comment: @Dallin I did update composer json as you suggested. also I followed SaintPlay answer. but it did not seem to work properly. Like few pages did work when I use models inside a controller. but some of the pages still throw App\ModelName Error. the model does not seem to reflect the change. I couple of times did dump-autoload and also did cache:clear, view:clear. How can I debug these issue?

Comment: @Dallin I get these when I do composer dump-autoload `Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Models\Company" was found in both "$baseDir . '/app/Models/Company.php" and "C:/Users/murli/laravel/Bookings/app/models/Company.php", the fi
rst will be used.
`

Comment: I have had this exact same issue, and found the solution lies in making sure the references are 100% correct. Changing "app/models" to "app/Models" fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Afer moving all files in the models folder. What you need to do is run:

`composer dump-autoload`

This worked for me. :)

Comment: Does this works without adding App\Models folders to composer.json's classmap ? If this, how is it posible? Anyway, I thinks it's needed to update namespace of each model, right?.

Comment: Have tried it with other projects of which it should work without adding classmap to composer.json. For more info checkout this link
https://medium.com/@codingcave/organizing-your-laravel-models-6b327db182f9

Answer (score 1):

After doing @Saint Play steps. I had to do `php artisan config:clear`. Then it worked !

Answer (score 0):

you need to reference your factory in the model by this :

```
    /**
     * Create a new factory instance for the model.
     *
     * @return ArticleFactory
     */
    protected static function newFactory(): ArticleFactory
    {
        return ArticleFactory::new();
    }
```

and in your factory define your model by `protected $model` like this :

```
class ArticleFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Article::class;
    
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => User::factory()->create()->id,
            'slug' => $this->faker->unique()->slug,
            // and other fields
        ];
    }
}
```