# Method not allowed with laravel echo server

Tags: php, laravel, socket.io

I changed models directory in laravel with models folder and followed these instructions to set everything up:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44080541/10230696

And now when ever user login or I restart laravel echo server while user is logged in I get error in command lines:

```
"message": "",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",
"file": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\laravelapp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php",
"line": 255,
.
.
.

Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 405
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like I can't run two times on same port even after quiting and killing process.

Also when I used php artisan serve it did not work but when I added as xampp folder in htdocs it worked perfectly, why I DO NOT KNOW!